# JAX-WS/Webservices log request/response raw XMLs

Tags: xml, web-services, jax-ws, axis

Have a webservices class annotated by

```
@javax.jws.WebService
```

I would need to log the raw request and response xmls to the database. Couldnt think of/find anyway i can do this.

Please help !!

Answer (score 4):

Very easy. Have a look [here](http://www.centurion.link/w/programming/java/jax#how_can_i_see_the_soap_messages_send_between_client_and_server_is_there_any_way_to_dump_them):

`-Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true -Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump=true`

For more selective logging you can use interceptors, check [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9173149/267197).